# Text based naval game

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, console

here is the second game I have made. its not easy and I was hoping someone could test it and bring some improvements to the table. fun project for learning.

```
import random

class Ship:
def __init__(self, name, symbol, position):
    self.name = name
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.health = 100
    self.crew = 100
    self.position = position
    self.cannonballs = 100
    self.morale = 100
    self.morale_boost_wait_turns = 0
    self.enemy = None

def move(self, distance):
    new_position = self.position + distance
    if 0 <= new_position <= 6 and new_position != self.enemy.position:
        self.position = new_position
        print(f"{self.name} moved to position {new_position}.")
    else:
        print("Invalid move!")

def crew_attack(self, enemy_ship):
    if abs(self.position - enemy_ship.position) in range(1, 3):
        damage = random.randint(5, 10)
        enemy_ship.health -= damage
        self.crew -= random.randint(5, 10)
        print(f"{self.name} executed a crew attack! {damage} damage dealt to {enemy_ship.name}.")
    else:
        print("Crew attack is not possible at this distance!")

def cannon_attack(self, enemy_ship):
    if abs(self.position - enemy_ship.position) in range(3, 5):
        damage = random.randint(10, 20)
        enemy_ship.health -= damage
        self.cannonballs -= random.randint(10, 20)
        print(f"{self.name} executed a cannon attack! {damage} damage dealt to {enemy_ship.name}.")
    else:
        print("Cannon attack is not possible at this distance!")

def ram_attack(self, enemy_ship):
    if abs(self.position - enemy_ship.position) >= 5:
        damage = random.randint(20, 30)
        enemy_ship.health -= damage
        if self.position < enemy_ship.position:
            self.position = min(enemy_ship.position - 1, 6)
        else:
            self.position = max(enemy_ship.position + 1, 0)
        print(f"{self.name} executed a ram attack! {damage} damage dealt to {enemy_ship.name}.")
        print(f"{self.name} moved to position {self.position}.")
    else:
        print("Ram attack is not possible at this distance!")

def repair(self):
    if self.crew >= 10:
        restored_health = random.randint(10, 20)
        self.health += restored_health
        self.crew -= 10
        print(f"{self.name} repaired their ship. Health restored by {restored_health}.")
    else:
        print("Insufficient crew members for repair.")

def steal_crew_members(self):
    if abs(self.position - self.enemy.position) == 1:
        stolen_crew = random.randint(5, 10)
        self.crew += stolen_crew
        self.enemy.crew -= stolen_crew
        print(f"{self.name} stole {stolen_crew} crew members from {self.enemy.name}!")

def morale_booster(self):
    if self.crew >= 20:
        if self.morale_boost_wait_turns == 0:
            morale_boost_amount = random.randint(15, 20) * (self.crew // 10)
            self.morale += morale_boost_amount
            self.crew -= 20
            self.morale_boost_wait_turns = 3  # Crew members need to wait 3 turns before using morale booster again
            print(f"{self.name} used a morale booster. Morale boosted by {morale_boost_amount}.")
        else:
            print("Crew members need to wait before using the morale booster again.")
    else:
        print("Insufficient crew members for morale booster.")

def update_morale_boost_wait_turns(self):
    if self.morale_boost_wait_turns > 0:
        self.morale_boost_wait_turns -= 1

def is_alive(self):
    return self.health > 0 and self.crew > 0


def display_distance_bar(player1, player2):
bar = [" "] * 7  # Initialize the bar with 7 empty slots
bar[player1.position] = player1.symbol
bar[player2.position] = player2.symbol

# Adjust positions if they overlap or go beyond the valid range
if player1.position == player2.position:
    bar[player1.position] = "X"  # Mark overlapping position with "X"
elif player1.position > player2.position:
    bar[player1.position] = ">"  # Mark player1's position with ">"
    bar[player2.position] = "<"  # Mark player2's position with "<"

distance_bar = "|".join(bar)
print(f"Distance Bar: {distance_bar}")


def display_stats(player):
print(f"{player.name}'s Stats:")
print(f"Health: {player.health}")
print(f"Crew: {player.crew}")
print(f"Position: {player.position}")
print(f"Cannonballs: {player.cannonballs}")
print(f"Morale: {player.morale}")
print(f"Morale Boost Turns Remaining: {player.morale_boost_wait_turns}")


def main():
print("==== Welcome to Jolley Roger ====")
player1_name = input("Player 1, enter your name: ")
player2_name = input("Player 2, enter your name: ")

player1 = Ship(player1_name, player1_name[0], 0)
player2 = Ship(player2_name, player2_name[0], 6)
player1.enemy = player2
player2.enemy = player1

while player1.is_alive() and player2.is_alive():
    print("\nPlayer 1's Turn:")
    display_stats(player1)
    display_distance_bar(player1, player2)
    steps = int(input("Enter the number of steps to move (0-3): "))
    if steps != 0:
        direction = input("Enter the direction to move (left or right): ")
        if direction == "left":
            steps *= -1
        player1.move(steps)

    print("\nPlayer 1's Turn - Action Menu:")
    display_stats(player1)
    display_distance_bar(player1, player2)
    print("Choose an action:")
    print("1. Crew Attack (1-2 distance)")
    print("2. Cannon Attack (3-4 distance)")
    print("3. Ram Attack (5+ distance)")
    print("4. Repair")
    print("5. Steal Crew Members")
    print("6. Morale Booster")
    choice = int(input())

    if choice == 1:
        player1.crew_attack(player2)
    elif choice == 2:
        player1.cannon_attack(player2)
    elif choice == 3:
        player1.ram_attack(player2)
    elif choice == 4:
        player1.repair()
    elif choice == 5:
        player1.steal_crew_members()
    elif choice == 6:
        player1.morale_booster()

    player1.update_morale_boost_wait_turns()

    print("\nPlayer 2's Turn:")
    display_stats(player2)
    display_distance_bar(player1, player2)
    steps = int(input("Enter the number of steps to move (0-3): "))
    if steps != 0:
        direction = input("Enter the direction to move (left or right): ")
        if direction == "left":
            steps *= -1
        player2.move(steps)

    print("\nPlayer 2's Turn - Action Menu:")
    display_stats(player2)
    display_distance_bar(player1, player2)
    print("Choose an action:")
    print("1. Crew Attack (1-2 distance)")
    print("2. Cannon Attack (3-4 distance)")
    print("3. Ram Attack (5+ distance)")
    print("4. Repair")
    print("5. Steal Crew Members")
    print("6. Morale Booster")
    choice = int(input())

    if choice == 1:
        player2.crew_attack(player1)
    elif choice == 2:
        player2.cannon_attack(player1)
    elif choice == 3:
        player2.ram_attack(player1)
    elif choice == 4:
        player2.repair()
    elif choice == 5:
        player2.steal_crew_members()
    elif choice == 6:
        player2.morale_booster()

    player2.update_morale_boost_wait_turns()

if player1.is_alive():
    print(f"\n{player1.name} won the battle!")
elif player2.is_alive():
    print(f"\n{player2.name} won the battle!")
else:
    print("\nIt's a draw!")

print("==== Game Over ====")


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Additionally, it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: The indentation seems off. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good, but there are a few improvements to be made.

---

First, the repeated code. You repeat the same code for `player1` and `player2`, when you could just use a method:

```py
# inside the Ship class
def turn(self):
    print(f"\n{self.name}'s Turn:")
    display_stats(self)
    display_distance_bar(self, self.enemy)

    steps = int(input("Enter the number of steps to move (0-3): "))

    if steps != 0:
        direction = input("Enter the direction to move (left or right): ")
        if direction == "left":
            steps *= -1
        player1.move(steps)

    print("\nPlayer 1's Turn - Action Menu:")
    display_stats(self)
    display_distance_bar(self, self.enemy)
    print("Choose an action:")
    print("1. Crew Attack (1-2 distance)")
    print("2. Cannon Attack (3-4 distance)")
    print("3. Ram Attack (5+ distance)")
    print("4. Repair")
    print("5. Steal Crew Members")
    print("6. Morale Booster")
    choice = int(input())

    if choice == 1:
        self.crew_attack(self.enemy)
    elif choice == 2:
        self.cannon_attack(self.enemy)
    elif choice == 3:
        self.ram_attack(self.enemy)
    elif choice == 4:
        self.repair()
    elif choice == 5:
        self.steal_crew_members()
    elif choice == 6:
        self.morale_booster()

    self.update_morale_boost_wait_turns()
```

I would also advise you to use a match-case statement:

```py
def turn(self):
    ...
    choice = int(input())

    match choice:
        case 1:
            self.crew_attack(self.enemy)
        case 2:
            self.cannon_attack(self.enemy)
    ...
```

---

You could also make some of your existing functions into methods, for example `display_distance_bar()`:

```py
# inside Ship class

def display_distance_bar(self):
    bar = [" "] * 7  # Initialize the bar with 7 empty slots
    bar[self.position] = self.symbol
    bar[self.enemy.position] = self.enemy.symbol

    # Adjust positions if they overlap or go beyond the valid range
    if self.position == self.enemy.position:
        bar[self.position] = "X"  # Mark overlapping position with "X"

    elif self.position > self.enemy.position:
        bar[self.position] = ">"  # Mark player1's position with ">"
        bar[self.enemy.position] = "<"  # Mark player2's position with "<"

    distance_bar = "|".join(bar)
    print(f"Distance Bar: {distance_bar}")
```

This would also work for `display_stats()`.

---

The game loop would now look something like:

```py
def main():
    print("==== Welcome to Jolley Roger ====")
    player1_name = input("Player 1, enter your name: ")
    player2_name = input("Player 2, enter your name: ")

    player1 = Ship(player1_name, player1_name[0], 0)
    player2 = Ship(player2_name, player2_name[0], 6)
    player1.enemy = player2
    player2.enemy = player1

    while player1.is_alive() and player2.is_alive():
        player1.turn()
        player2.turn()

    if player1.is_alive():
        print(f"\n{player1.name} won the battle!")
    elif player2.is_alive():
        print(f"\n{player2.name} won the battle!")
    else:
        print("\nIt's a draw!")

    print("==== Game Over ====")
```

---

N.B.
Your indentation is also wrong but I assume that's from incorrect copy and pasting.

---

Overall, a very engaging text-based game.